# Can we change the color of tabs in Android

Tags: android

I want to change the colors of each tabs. For example, I want to make the first tab red, and second tab is green and third is blue and etc.. (like in below) and there will be no text in my tabs, i will put just icon.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be some code within the smali (if you are coding in smali? - if not compile your app and then decompile using apktool) that should reference for color and a some code referencing 'inherit from parent'. This is a reference to the framework it's self. You can in some cases over-ride by providing a reference to a specified hex code color after the > symbol in of the line specific to color.

You will need to specify a different hex code for each tabs smali class. You may also need to check there are no "global" overrides that will always reference back to the framework. These will take precedent over any hex that you may specify. I had troubles with this myself when I was trying to theme the pop-up menus on Samsung Galaxy S2 to have the teal green of the current Galaxy S3 at the time. It can get quite tricky but be patient.